# Bitcoin Widgets & API

Tags: api, altcoin, currencies, charts, ticker

can anyone recommend the best api/widget for getting Bitcoin, Crypto Currency Charts, Currency Convert and tickers?

Comment: Which platform do you want widgets for? Android, iOS  or something else?